# Hide rep during review audits

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

I just encountered [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/2329953) and quality of the audit itself aside, the rep of the user more or less invalidated the audit before I even had to read the answer. I know audits are suppose to be a "gotcha" thing and is just meant to punish robo-reviewers but having the rep/badge count displayed is a dead giveaway.

A reviewer can just take a look at the rep/badge count and if it does not look like a new account, >100 rep, silver or gold badges, then it is for sure an audit; not to mention audits with a deleted account.

Since the up/downvote count is hidden for an audit, I hope it would not be a difficult change to hide the rep/badge count as well.

Comment: I dont think a typical click-through reviewer looks at rep and badges. However, this would be a positive change so no issues :)

Comment: Not a bad idea. Would be a bit pointless for the 'First Posts' review though, (obviously!) but still probably useful for the others.

Comment: I like it. But keep in mind that when reviewing (let's say suggested edits), scrolling down, looking at the users' reputation, judging wheteher you should suspect an audit or not is almost as long as reviewing the edit itself. So I guess robo-reviwers won't care. I'm sure they don't event know you can see the users reputation.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd the link addresses similar issues. I couldn't find it during my searches, but we can roll the 2 suggestions into 1 I wouldn't mind closing this one as dup

Comment: Think that if anything, it's better to hide the whole card and be done with.